# Next.js - Vercel deployment error: Error: EEXIST: file already exists

Tags: typescript, next.js, vercel

Getting the following error in Vercel **preview** deployment with Next.js 13.0.0.

My understanding is the preview deployment runs on any branch update.

It seems that the `api` dynamic routing doesn't work correctly because the error occurs on `address/[zipcode].ts`.

I have no idea how to fix the error. Any re-deployment does not work as well.

[image]

Re-deployment

[image]

This is the directory structure.

```
├── pages
│   ├── _app.tsx
│   ├── account
│   │   ├── signIn.tsx
│   │   └── signUp.tsx
│   ├── admin
│   │   └── registration.tsx
│   ├── api
│   │   ├── address
│   │   │   └── [zipcode].ts <-- Subjective file
│   │   ├── artWork
│   │   │   └── index.ts
│   │   ├── artWorks
│   │   │   └── index.ts
│   │   ├── genres
│   │   │   └── index.ts
│   │   ├── relatedArtWorks
│   │   │   └── index.ts
│   │   ├── signUp
│   │   │   └── index.ts
│   │   ├── spotlightArtWorks
│   │   │   └── index.ts
│   │   └── user
│   │       └── index.ts
│   ├── galleries
│   │   └── [artistId]
...
```

Please help.